# The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'table', database 'db', schema 'dbo'.

Tags: sql, database

Im getting this error in my development machine:

"The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'table', database 'db', schema 'dbo'.", and I don't know why, i tried this and don't even work.

```
GRANT SELECT
ON my_table
TO public
GO
```

And this

```
GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].my_table TO myUser
```

Im using an XML file to connect to the database:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Development>
    <Server>localhost</Server>
    <Db>MyDB</Db>
    <User>myUser</User>
    <Pass>myPass</Pass>
    <IntegratedSecurity>No</IntegratedSecurity>
</Development>
```

The most weird part is the user is in the Security of my Database:
http://puu.sh/bWovD/50d4646602.png

Hope anyone can help me please

Comment: Maybe you are trying to authenticate with a different user than what was entered during the setup. If you remember the sa password, log in with that one, and grant access to this other account.

Comment: @Alex , thank you so much!, that was the answer, I create the database with myUser, and execute all the script to fill all my db and worth! :D

How can I put your comment as an Answer?

Answer (score 1):

grant db_datareader access to your user.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but im getting this message "Cannot find the object 'db_datareader', because it does not exist or you do not have permission." executing this "grant exec on db_datareader to myUser"

Comment: @NESTicle What version of MSSQL are you using? Are you logging in as sysadmin to grant access?